# mongodb сама по себе периодически выключается

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mongodb

mongodb стоит на ubuntu 18.4.

Почему то периодически она сама стопится. Как разобраться в причинах. Или как настроить автоматический перезапуск (sudo service mongod start)

Comment: по идее у Вас должен быть лог файл по пути /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log, нужно его проанализировать.

Comment: sudo service mongod enable - автоматический перезапуск

Comment: @СергейКоновалов, выдает подобный ответ mongod: unrecognized service